# Can a father use his son's first name as a pseudonym to publish his writing?

Tags: personality

I have a friend. Let's call him John Smith. John Smith has a son. I'll call him Robert Smith. John, their family and Robert's friends all call the child Robert or Robby. No one calls him Rob.

Now, in his free time John writes novels. He wants to publish them under a pseudonym, and the perfect pseudonym he came up with for his writer self is Rob James Ford. (I'm still making up all the names, but the principle of similarity is the same.)

John Smith is a bit worried how his son will feel when he grows up and discovers that his father has "appropriated" his own name.

Little Robert is eight years old today and knows quite a few other Roberts, among them one of his best friends, so he is used to the fact that his name is not exclusive to him. But he also knows his father by the name John and that Rob is one possible short form of Robert. When he reaches adolescence and has to find his adult identity -- possibly accompanied by conflicts with his father -- he might feel that his father has been transgressing into what is rightfully his own by using his name for himself. It might feel wrong to Rob Smith that his father calls himself Rob Ford.

What do you think?

Is it unproblematic for John to call himself Rob? After all he does not call himself Rob Smith but uses a different last name with a version of his son's first name, so there is no mistaking Rob James Ford for Rob(ert) Smith. But at the same time Rob *is* the name of John's son, and they both recognize this.

What should John do?

John found his pseudonym through a painstaking process and has been unable to come up with another pseudonym that feels just as right to him. Giving up Rob as part of his pseudonym would be a pity.

Comment: This is interesting, I think, but I'm not sure if it's too opinion-based. I wonder whether experiences of shared-name families (e.g. John Smith and John Smith Jr) would be relevant?

Comment: Also, at 8, it could be feasible for John to have a chat with Robert about the pseudonym Rob. If it's a concept that Robert grows up with, it may be less problematic during adolescence (as opposed to, say, discovering by happenstance that his father uses "Rob" for some circumstances)

Comment: @Erica John Smith Jr grows up with his father having the same name. Having Rob grow up with knowing about his father's pseudonym would probably cause a similar habituation and "un-weird" the whole issue. Great idea!

Comment: This question isn't really a parenting question - it's very opinion based, and possibly strays into legal territory we can't advise on here.

Comment: The legal aspect is not part of the question. The question asks about the emotions of a child in relation to the behavior of a parent and a parent's responsibility towards his son. If this is not parenting then I don't know what is. And it is no more opinion based than the other questions on this site, or do you actually believe that there is one right way to raise children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If John is not using "Rob Smith" and is instead using "Rob Ford" it doesn't seem like it would be much of an issue. No one will ask the adult Robert Smith , "Hey are you also that author Rob Ford?"

Also if the novels become really big and John has book signings he wouldn't be spoken to using the psudoname he would still be called John Smith if he was attending in person.

If that doesn't work, what about asking 8 year old Robert what he thinks? You could explain the situation and see if he has an issue with it. If Robert has a problem with it John should pick a different name.

Also Also, why cant John just pick a different name and avoid the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think part of it depends on how old you are, and if you're any good at writing.

If you're really good (able to make a ton of money from your writing), you want the real Rob to get his share of the money in return for your theft of his name. So you want to protect the book(s) for as long as possible. If you're old and expect to die soon, a pseudonym will protect your work longer.

> if you use your real name, protection for the work extends for your life plus seventy years; if you use a pseudonym, the term of protection is 95 years from the publication of the work, or 120 years from the creation of the work, whichever period expires first.

If you don't die, or the pseudonym is found to be associated with you, that advantage vanishes:

> If, however, after filing the original application in a pen name, the author’s identity is later revealed in the records, the term reverts to the life of the author plus 70 years.

I think (again, POB) that if you're really good, your child *can* take it as a compliment. If, however, he doesn't like your writing, he might be insulted.

I say, avoid it altogether. If you are imaginative enough to write, you should be imaginative enough to make up a better pseudonym that in no way reflects upon an innocent party.

<sub>[Publishing FAQ](http://publishlawyer.com/publishing-faq/)</sub>

Comment: Ha! Interesting argument :-) As for  being imaginative enough to write, I can understand that sometimes things just "click" and that giving up something not for an inherent but external reason will prevent things from clicking again: your imagination is blocked by the perfect fit.